# Highcharts dynamic binding in c# or json

Tags: c#, json, highcharts

I would like to know how to bind mutliseries spline high charts dynamic way in c#

The sample jsfiddle is static format.

[Statciway](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-basic/)

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
            x: -20
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Temperature (°C)'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: '°C'
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
        }, {
            name: 'New York',
            data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
        }, {
            name: 'Berlin',
            data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
        }, {
            name: 'London',
            data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
        }]
    });
});
```

I can get Tokyo, Newyork, London data in c# but I'm not sure how to bind this data in series

Any links or help would be really appreciated mates.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a Json object with the same representation as the structure used in the static example.  If you only want parts of it, (e.g. the data) then just create a JSON object for the parts you want.

```
   xAxis: {
        categories: myJsonObject
    }
```

Alternatively you can try DotNet Highcharts 
http://dotnethighcharts.codeplex.com/

This will give a load of server side wrappers for the highchart properties

Comment: Thnaks mate. For single series i'm able to done easily. But multiple series only not able to bind. I'm searching in google thoroughly to get my answer some where

Comment: For multiple series it's really just arrays of arrays. You can use http://json2csharp.com/ to generate C# classes to match the expected json format then all you have to do is serialize the class to Json.  I would recommend looking at the DotNetHighcharts though, takes a lot of the pain out.